# Rename Pandas DataFrame via list iteration

Tags: python, pandas

I created my Pandas list the following:

```
id=[f'GeneID_region_{i}' for i in range(43)]
value=[f'GeneValue_region_{i}' for i in range(43)]


lst=[]
for i in range(43):
    lst.append(id[i])
    lst.append(value[i])



df=pd.DataFrame(index=lst).T
```

So now it looks like: df(0, 86)

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [GeneID_region_0, GeneValue_region_0, GeneID_region_1, GeneValue_region_1, GeneID_region_2, GeneValue_region_2, GeneID_region_3, GeneValue_region_3, GeneID_region_4, GeneValue_region_4, GeneID_region_5, GeneValue_region_5, GeneID_region_6, GeneValue_region_6, GeneID_region_7, GeneValue_region_7, GeneID_region_8, GeneValue_region_8, GeneID_region_9, GeneValue_region_9, GeneID_region_10, GeneValue_region_10, GeneID_region_11, GeneValue_region_11, GeneID_region_12, GeneValue_region_12, GeneID_region_13, GeneValue_region_13, GeneID_region_14, GeneValue_region_14, GeneID_region_15, GeneValue_region_15, GeneID_region_16, GeneValue_region_16, GeneID_region_17, GeneValue_region_17, GeneID_region_18, GeneValue_region_18, GeneID_region_19, GeneValue_region_19, GeneID_region_20, GeneValue_region_20, GeneID_region_21, GeneValue_region_21, GeneID_region_22, GeneValue_region_22, GeneID_region_23, GeneValue_region_23, GeneID_region_24, GeneValue_region_24, GeneID_region_25, GeneValue_region_25, GeneID_region_26, GeneValue_region_26, GeneID_region_27, GeneValue_region_27, GeneID_region_28, GeneValue_region_28, GeneID_region_29, GeneValue_region_29, GeneID_region_30, GeneValue_region_30, GeneID_region_31, GeneValue_region_31, GeneID_region_32, GeneValue_region_32, GeneID_region_33, GeneValue_region_33, GeneID_region_34, GeneValue_region_34, GeneID_region_35, GeneValue_region_35, GeneID_region_36, GeneValue_region_36, GeneID_region_37, GeneValue_region_37, GeneID_region_38, GeneValue_region_38, GeneID_region_39, GeneValue_region_39, GeneID_region_40, GeneValue_region_40, GeneID_region_41, GeneValue_region_41, GeneID_region_42, GeneValue_region_42]
Index: []

[0 rows x 86 columns]
```

After I did some processing and stuff with my df, I want to replace the column names.

I am reading in a Textfile with names, that I want to use:

```
with open('/home/anja/Schreibtisch/Master/ABA/layer2_names.txt') as f:
    layernames = [line.strip() for line in f.read().split('\n')]
```

And now I tried this:

```
df.rename(columns={[f'GeneID_region_{i}' for i in range(43)]: ['GeneID_region_{i}' for i in layernames]}, inplace=True)
```

But this gives me 
>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Has someone a solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not creating a dictionary in the right way. This is just trying to create a dictionary using both lists as unique `key` and `value` which is giving you an error, since lists are not hashable. You can use `zip` here to interleave its items and *then* build a dictionary:

```
d = dict(zip([f'GeneID_region_{i}' for i in range(43)],
             [f'GeneID_region_{i}' for i in layernames]))
df.rename(columns=d, inplace=True)
```

Or alternatively you could use:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.rsplit('_',1).str[0].str.cat(layernames,sep='_')
```